# Packaging a custom Java `partitioner.class` plugin for Kafka Connect in Confluent 4.1 + Kafka 1.1?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've been successfully using a simple custom Partitioner class written in Java for a Kafka Connect sink on Confluent 3.2.x (Kafka 0.10.x). I want to upgrade to Confluent 4.1 (Kafka 1.1) and am experiencing errors.

Kafka Connect's plugin loading mechanism seems to have been changed in CP 3.3.0. Previously, there was just the CLASSPATH option, but with CP 3.3.0+ there is a newer and recommended `plugin.path` mechanism.

If I try to keep using the legacy CLASSPATH plugin mechanism, when I try to use my plugin, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
```

That is a CP internal class. With the older CP 3.2.x, that was available on the classpath, however with the new classpath isolation efforts in CP >= 3.3.0, I presume that must be provided along with the plugin.

I figure it's wise to switch to the newer recommended `plugin.path` mechanism. I remove the CLASSPATH entry. In the default `/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties`, I see `plugin.path=/usr/share/java`, so I install my plugin .jar to `/usr/share/java/my-custom-partitioner/my-custom-partitioner.jar`. I have tried adding and not adding dependency .jar files there as well.

My plugin seems to get loaded when the Kafka Connect service starts up:

```
INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/share/java/my-custom-partitioner (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/my-custom-partitioner/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
```

When I do:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@sink_test_1.json" my-dev-test-vm:8083/connectors/sink-test-1/config
```

I get:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":null}%
```

I can see in the kafka connect systemd log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig.classNameEquals(PartitionerConfig.java:270)
at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig.access$000(PartitionerConfig.java:33)
at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig$PartitionerClassDependentsRecommender.visible(PartitionerConfig.java:238)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:617)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:625)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:525)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validateAll(ConfigDef.java:508)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.validate(ConfigDef.java:490)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Connector.validate(Connector.java:133)
```

It's not apparent what is going wrong or why my partitioner class isn't loading correctly.

FYI, I have rebuilt my Java plugin with CP 4.1 + Kafka 1.1 dependencies and made small updates to match API changes such as adding an implementation for `getSchemaGeneratorClass` to my partitioner class.

Comment: Either `left` or `right` is null... https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/v4.1.0/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/PartitionerConfig.java#L270

Comment: I've found that putting my custom partitioner in `share/java/kafka-storage-common` works fine

Comment: walk up the stack trace to line 238 in the same file. left is always `DefaultPartitioner.class`. right is null. But why? Clearly some problem happened elsewhere in the code base.

Comment: There's something wrong with classpath loader, I agree. As mentioned, sticking a JAR in the common directory seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Kafka Connect Partitioner classes will not work via the old CLASSPATH mechanism and they will not work as plugins with the newer Kafka 0.11.0+ isolated plugin mechanism.

The only working solution is to copy your custom .jar file with your custom Kafka Connect Partitioner class into the `kafka-connect-storage-common` plugin directorry at `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common/`. Custom Kafka Connect Partitioner plugin classes must exist in that same directory so they are in the same isolated class loader.

FYI, you can see that the Kafka 0.11.0+ isolated plugin mechanism will only load subclasses of four specific Java classes that do not cover the Kafka Connect partitioners here:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/fdcf75ea326b8e07d8d7c4f5cc14f1e70451bcd4/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/isolation/DelegatingClassLoader.java#L279

Thanks to cricket_007 for recommending this exact solution: putting custom Kafka Connect partitioner .jar files in the `/share/java/kafka-storage-common` directory. I learned the hard way exactly why this has to be done and why alternatives don't work.