# Implementing a kafka connect custom partitioner

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using confluent's kafka connect to pipe data into a s3 bucket. Ideally partitioned based on a key. Since the existing FieldPartitioner only works for Avro schema records and not for general stringnified JSON texts. I thought i'd write my own connector.

Here's the class:

```
package com.package.kafka.connect;


import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner;
import io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.*;

public class JsonFieldPartitioner<T> extends DefaultPartitioner<T> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FieldPartitioner.class);
    private List<String> fieldNames;
    private List<String> keys;

    public void configure(Map<String, Object> config){
        fieldNames = (List<String>) config.get("partition.field.name");
        String field =  fieldNames.get(0);
        keys = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(field.split(".")));
    }

    public String encodePartition(SinkRecord sinkRecord){
        String value = sinkRecord.value().toString();

        JsonElement rootElement = new JsonParser().parse(value);
        JsonElement element = rootElement;

        for(String key : keys){
            log.info("key: "+ key);
            try{
                element = element.getAsJsonObject().get(key);
            }catch(Exception e){
                log.error("encountered error getting key: " + key);
                throw new ConfigException("Key element not found" + key);
            }
        }

        String fieldValue  = "";
        try{
            fieldValue =  element.getAsString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("encountered error getting key value ");
            throw new ConfigException("Key element not found");
        }
        return fieldValue;
    }

    public List<T> partitionFields() {
        if (partitionFields == null) {
            partitionFields = newSchemaGenerator(config).newPartitionFields(
                    Utils.join(fieldNames, ",")
            );
        }
        return partitionFields;
    }
}
```

When I build it and try to run kafka connect I get an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig.classNameEquals(PartitionerConfig.java:269)
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig.access$000(PartitionerConfig.java:32)
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig$PartitionerClassDependentsRecommender.visible(
```

from looking at [Packaging a custom Java `partitioner.class` plugin for Kafka Connect in Confluent 4.1 + Kafka 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121329/packaging-a-custom-java-partitioner-class-plugin-for-kafka-connect-in-confluen)
I've tried to put the jar file built by this in the `kafka-connect-storage-common` directory in $CONFLUENT_HOME but I still get the same error.

The gradle file to build the jar is here

```
    id 'java'
}

group 'JsonFieldPartitioner'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'connect-api', version: '2.3.0'
    compile fileTree( dir:'/Users/myuser/confluent-5.3.0/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.3'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

and in the s3 connector properties file i just reference the class by `com.package.kafka.connect.JsonFieldPartitioner`

If anyone has had success building custom partitioners, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your custom jar file under plugin folder 
Example 
/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3/

Comment: Is there any way to make it easy? What if we need to share the same partitioner with sink/source connectors? Does it mean we need to modify their `kafka-connect-storage-partitioner.jar` too?

Comment: you don't need to modify anything. just copy your custom jar inside plugin folder.example /usr/local/share/kafka/plugins/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3/

Comment: Yeah, you answer was edited. My comment does not make sense anymore. Coping jar is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

while preparing kafka connect image :- we could do

```
confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/connect-fieldandtime-partitioner-1.2.0.zip
```

here the zip is custom partitioner then why do we need to place the JAR in lib folder of Service